# cypress waitForReact() require.resolve is not a function

Tags: reactjs, webpack, cypress, react-testing-library

I'm trying to use **cypress-react-selector** to test the state of react components with Cypress framework.
Following the guide here I've installed it https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-react-selector#find-element-by-react-component and modified cypress/support/index.js

Unfortunately  the test always fails on the command Cy.waitForReact() saying:

```
Error:    TypeError: require.resolve is not a function

Because this error occurred during a 'before all' hook we are skipping the remaining tests in the current suite: 'Try checks in mapping table'
    at Context.exports.waitForReact (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\support\index.js-307:404:23)
```

Clicking at that console link it seems the error is in the line:

```
cy.readFile(require.resolve('resq'), 'utf8', {
```

**I don't understand what's happening, do anyone have a solution for this error?**

test:

```
describe("test sample", () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.visit("/myurl/586");
    cy.waitForReact();
  });

  it('check length of state"', () => {
    cy.react("TableBody").should("have.length", "3");
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: An [issue](https://github.com/abhinaba-ghosh/cypress-react-selector/issues/94) has been raised for this.

Comment: Maybe caused by the last [pull request](https://github.com/abhinaba-ghosh/cypress-react-selector/pull/90). Try installing specific version 2.2.0 which does not use `require.resolve`.